# My React native app with multiple modals is not working properly

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, native

I have created a react native card game with multiple modals using chatGPT. This because i'm new to coding. The problem that im facing right now is that whenever multiple conditions are met the modal that has to come next does not show up and i can not click for the next card.

if the conditions of the modal are met i want all of the modals with that condition to show and be able to continue the game

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.